# How do I delete characters from the beginning of a paragraph in a NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I'm working on adding lists/bullets to a NSTextView, and now I'm working on changing a bulleted paragraph back to a normal one when the user selects the toggle bullets button. In order to do that, I've figured out how to check if the paragraph is in a bulleted style and change the rest of the style, but I need to be able to delete the first three characters (with the bullet glyph) from the paragraph. Ideally, I would then place the insertion cursor at the end of the paragraph. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

In your class files, you'd have an NSString (with the bulleted paragraphs) and that NSString is then put into your textview, right?

To take out all the bullet symbol text pieces, you'd simply do:

```
NSString *paragraphsWithBullets = @"(bullet) paragraph";

if ([paragraphsWithBullets rangeOfString:@"bullet"].location == NSNotFound) {

// string doesn't contain bullets
textview.text = paragraphsWithBullets;

} else {

// string does contain bullets
NSString *paragraphWithoutBullets = [paragraphsWithBullets stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"bullet" withString:@""];

textview.text = paragraphWithoutBullets;

}
```